# What's wrong with my code that uses Pug and jQuery together?

Tags: javascript, jquery, pug

Can somebody please tell me what to change here? I am trying to generate a navigation bar using [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) and [Pug](https://pugjs.org/).  Similar code works when implemented in HTML, but the rest of my code is written in Pug and I cannot seem to make the necessary adjustments.  Thank you!

#### Pug

```
doctype html
html
  head
  body
    .header
    .main-content
      a(href="#testtag" class="test2") The button bar should appear here
```

#### JavaScript

```js
jQuery(function($){
   place_buttons;
})(jQuery);

function place_buttons() {
  $('#a.test').on('click', function() {
    var navBar =
       '<a href="#dataList" class="fp"> &laquo; </a>' +
       '<a href="#dataList" class="pp"> Previous page </a>' +
       '<a href="#dataList" class="np"> Next Page </a>' +
       '<a href="#dataList" class="lp"> &raquo; </a>';

    $('#a.test').html(navBar);
  })
}
```

#### Output

> The button bar should appear here

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the JS console or from the pug compiler?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything matching `$('#a.test')` outputted by Pug. There's an anchor with the class `test2` though ?

Comment: Also, `place_buttons` is never called in that code ?

Comment: Sorry, adeno  The typo (test2 as v test) is from my attempts to minimize test code.  If you use a.test throughout there are no errors and the output is the same.

Comment: place_buttons is called by the initialization program (the first three lines in the javascript code

Comment: No, it's not, to call a function, you would do `place_button()` <- note the parentheses.

Comment: Sorry, I have tried using parentheses in previous iterations and just put them back in for good measure. Same wrong result.

Comment: And there's no errors in the console? Try it like this -> https://jsfiddle.net/p36ogm4t/

Comment: Hi adeno,  thank you for the suggestion.  I am new to debugging tools and have been using JS Bin as JS Fiddle does not seem to accomodate pug.  I am not certain if you will be able to hope it, but it is here: http://jsbin.com/yebihulalo/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Voila -> http://jsbin.com/jediqelaga/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Merci!!!  Now how do I indicate that you have provided the answer??

Comment: adeno, or anyone Can you suggest a reason that the code does not work when implemented in my environment on a localhost?  I have tried everything I can imagine.

Comment: Solved it.  As expected - I had a problem with the rest of my program.